# java getRuntime().exec() does not work

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04, shellexecute

I am trying to use Java exec to run my Script and get the result and use it in my program.

I have following lines of code.

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("phantomjs quebecPhantom.js");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    String line = in.readLine();

    System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + line + "'");
}
```

I expect my `PhantomJS Script` to be executed and the `line` variable take the output of the `Script`. But, my script does not execute (It should take more time and it should produce some screen shots which I don't see). and then, the `line` variable takes the `null` value.

Should I consider anything more to have my Script executed?

Comment: Is the path to the `quebecPhantom.js` correct?

Comment: Is the path to phantomjs correct?

Comment: commons-exec : http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/

Comment: the Script for PhantomJS is in the same directory which my java code is in. Should I do anything special for the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the above lines of code is that I needed to get the path to the phantomjs and also to the script in the command I want to execute. then the line should be changed as follows,

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("path to phantomjs" + " " + "path to the script");
```

In my case that would be like

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/phantomjs /home/name/quebecPhantom.js");
```